# Set content of File as Variable in Python3 using os.system

Tags: python-3.x

My file called domain contains only 1 line

```
www.google.com
```

When I print my file using

```
cat domain
```

it prints me:

```
www.google.com
```

but when I try to assign it to my variable called "domain" it is an int according to visual studio code:

```
domain = os.system("cat ./domain")
```

and when I try to print the variable "domain" with

```
print(domain)
```

I get

```
0
```

How can I have it so I get a print of

```
www.google.com
```

instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get (0) is just the exit status of `cat`, which is 0 as there wasn't any error during its execution.

You can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module), as recommended by the doc of `os.system`:

```
import subprocess

res = subprocess.run(("cat", "./domain"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = res.stdout
```

Comment: I fixed it with file.read since it only contains one line and used strip() to remove any unnecessary "\n" in the file, which turned out to work too.